# How to stop a task with endless loop

Tags: c#, multithreading, button, task

actually it's a very simply question.

How can I Stop my Task ( with endless Loop) with a Stop button?

My Solution doesnt work, the user Interface is frozen after I use the start button. Thus I thought I can solute it with a bool stop variable

My Code:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApp5_Task_und_darstellun_test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaktionslogik für MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private bool stop;
        Transfer tr = new Transfer();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent(); 
        }
        private void listView1_SelectionChanged(object sender,
        SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
        }
        private void StartButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            stop = false;
            ObservableCollection<int> Data = new ObservableCollection<int>();
            do
            {
                new Task(() => { tr.GetData(Data); }).Start();
            } while (stop != true);

            listView1.ItemsSource = Data;
        }

        public void StopButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            stop = true;
        }
    }
    public class Transfer
    {
        public void GetData(ObservableCollection<int>data)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                    {
                        int d = i + j;
                        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                            new Action(() =>
                            {
                                data.Add(d); 
                            }));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I havent understood the issue INotifyPropertyChanged. Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: Unless you are writing a Task Schedueller you should never use `new Task(`, you need to use `Task.Run(` or if that is not available `Task.Factory.StartNew(`

Answer (score 2):

First we will add cancellation support to GetData method using [CacellationToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken(v=vs.110).aspx), otherwise there is no way you can really cancel the operation (you can stop waiting for it but the operation will still countinue and keep adding items to the collection and why would we want that?)

```
public class Transfer
{
    public void GetData(ObservableCollection<int>data, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    //Will throw OperationCanceledException if the operation was asked to be canceled
                    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    data.Add(d);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice we do not need to use the Dispacher here since the collection is not bounded to the UI at this point.

And then we can cancel the operation in Main Window using [CancellatonTokenSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource(v=vs.110).aspx), and [async and await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx) to prevent the UI from freezing when we will click the start button:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Transfer _transfer = new Transfer();

    private CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource ();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    private async void StartButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ObservableCollection<int> Data = new ObservableCollection<int>();
        try
        {
            await Task.Run(() => _transfer.GetData(Data, _cancellationTokenSource.Token);)
            listView1.ItemsSource = Data;
        }
        catch(OperationCanceledException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Canceled");
        }
    }

    private void StopButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    }
}
```

You can find more info in about Task Cancellation in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: unfortunately with this solution the start button won't work. Besides I dont wanna throw an exception if I press the stop button, I wanna exit the program.

Answer (score 0):

make a new function, put whats in StartButton_Click in that function, then setup a thread to do that function. This way your main thread keeps the UI alive and the thread in the background does the work.

Answer (score -1):

The following code stops endless while loop after 5 seconds

```
using CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken cancellationToken = source.Token;

var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    int a = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        a++;
        Console.WriteLine(a);
        if(cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
             break;
    }
}, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);

if (Task.WaitAny(new[] { task }, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)) == -1)
{
    source.Cancel();
}
```

`Task.WaitAny` waits for the tasks to complete execution. In the above code, if the task
does not execute in 5 seconds then the task will be cancelled.